# $product->addImageToMediaGallery() ignoring mediaAttribute parameter

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm adding images to products using the `addImageToMediaGallery()` function like so:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1234);

try {
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, ['small_image', 'thumbnail', 'image'], false, false);
    $product->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The images are uploaded to the gallery as intended but the media attributes (small_image, thumbnail, image) seem to be ignored and are not selected on the newly uploaded image.

[image: What I expected]

I'm running Magento CE 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting some more I have found a solution.

These values didn't change because there were other storeviews that didn't have "Use default value" selected

[image: settings]